# "Hello World" introduction for ubuntuGIS?

Tags: python, javascript, ubuntu, references, d3

Is the GIS equivalent of "Hello world!" = "You are here?"

I installed ubuntuGIS recently, but I'm a little overwhelmed navigating the network of many packages to begin accomplishing simple things.  I'd like to explore GIS more thoroughly (I have made maps using R and [techniques like these](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/)).

Are there any resources minimally illustrating going from...

Point A: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get install qgis` to

Point B: Here is a simple world map with a marker for your location?

Or could someone propose this "hello world" to get newbies started?  I think a tiny, simple project like this---"print where you are in the world" analogous to "print words on a screen" would be a very good learning tool for providing some narrative, tutorial context---something like giving a newbie a "roadmap" to making maps.

(Not required, but my personal preference on a thing like this would be that the output be [d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) or [kartograph](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/install-ubuntu.html#test-installation), something in-browser.)

Comment: Certainly not required, but care to explain the downvote?  What is undesirable in asking for a minimal working example of how to make a map plotting a point?  If you leave a comment I can better explain my question.

Answer (score 3):

As you've already discovered [UbuntuGIS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) is not a GIS itself but a [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) of GIS and related software. I suggest you try installing QGIS (from UbuntuGIS or [qgis.org](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu)) and having a look at the [How do I do that in QGIS](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/How_do_I_do_that_in_QGIS) page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that qgis is an important part of that.  It seems like a good step 2 after install the repository, but it's still a long trip from there to "here is the map."  The link you pointed to on QGIS was also not super helpful in this---the closest thing I could find to plotting any point was "plotting random points"(http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Creating_random_points) which was a 404...

Comment: See 1st 'How To' link - [Opening vector files](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Opening_vector_files)

Answer (score 2):

A good source of basic tutorials to get you started is the [OSGEO Live-DVD](http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/overview.html). It contains most of the open source GIS packages that you'll need to get started and each one has a quickstart and tutorial to get you going.